# Angular2 state management and the correct usage of @ngrx/store

Tags: angular, store, ngrx

I'm writing reducers for my application using ngrx/store.

Here is the layout of my application state:

```
{
    project: {
        name: string
        tasks: Array<Task>
    }
}

with:

interface Task {
    name: string
}
```

I'm trying to write clean reducers in separate files.

#### Here is the solution i'm currently using:

**project.reducer.ts**

```
import {tasksReducer} from './tasks.reducer';

const projectReducer = (state:Project = null, action: Action): Project => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CREATE_PROJECT':
            return {
                name :'New project',
                tasks: []
            };
    };

    state.tasks = tasksReducer( state.tasks, action );

    return state;
}
```

**tasks.reducer.ts**

```
export const tasksReducer = (state:Array<Task> = [], action: Action): Array<Task> => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TASK':
            return [...state, { name: 'New task' ];
        default:
            return state;
    };
}
```

**Store is provided using:**

```
StoreModule.provideStore( combineReducers([{
    project: projectReducer
}]) );
```

#### If i want to add other fields to my project, like a tags field:

```
{
    project: {
        name: string,
        tasks: Array<Task>,
        tags: Array<Tags>
    }
}
```

I can create a separate **tags.reducer.ts** and use the same approach to create the corresponding reducer.

#### *So what's wrong with this approach ?*

I'm pretty sure i'm running into troubles concerning the immutability of my application state.

*Exemple:*

- I dispatch the CREATE_PROJECT action, i get a new state and everything is OK.
- Then i dispatch a ADD_TASK action.

  - The tasksReducer itself return a brand new array of tasks, BUT the main application state is mutated ... And that is not good !

In your opinions, what's the best approach to solve this problem ?

#### More generally:

As my project object will grow bigger and bigger with more fields, how could i do to:

- Keep reducer separated
- Make reducer operate on isolated sub part of the 'main' reducer
- Keep my state immutable

I would be glad to share though and opinions about that !

Answer (score 2):

First of all some remarks around your projectReducer.
You are missing a default case in your switch statement, which is very important to have. (see http://blog.kwintenp.com/how-to-write-clean-reducers-and-test-them/#defaultcase). So add this to that reducer:

```
default:
   return state;
```

Secondly, you are doing something strange when calling your taskReducer. What you are doing when the projectReducer is called, is **always** calling your taskReducer. When in fact, you want to call the taskReducer if, and only if, it's an action he can do something with:

```
case 'ADD_TASK':
   // call it here
```

You are also overriding the current's state its task property. As you said, you are mutating your state, which is a definite thing to avoid. You can leverage the Object.assign operator to accomplish what you want like this (entire fix):

```
const projectReducer = (state:Project = null, action: Action): Project => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CREATE_PROJECT':
            return {
                name :'New project',
                tasks: []
            };
        case 'ADD_TASK':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {tasks: tasksReducer( state.tasks, action )};
        default:
            return state;
    };
}
```

Now you are creating a new Project object when you are changing something to the tasks, which is what you want.

I would recommend you to read my entire blogpost for some pointers on how to write reducers in a clean way.

Your general questions could have an elaborated answer but that would skip the point I guess. Some short answers below.

Keep reducer separated

--> You are using the combineReducers helper method, which is a good thing to keep your reducers separated.

Make reducer operate on isolated sub part of the 'main' reducer

--> Same as above

Keep my state immutable

--> Follow the tips in my blogpost and use the Object.assign and the spread operator when needed.

Comment: I agree with your proposition, but i have one main objection with this approach: **Separation of concerns**.  
The projectReducer MUST be aware of every action type implemented by the others 'sub reducers'.
Exemple: here projectReducer must be aware of the ADD_TASK action.
This sound problematic to me: As the project grow bigger, this will be error prone: for every new action added to a sub reducer, we have to think about modifying the root (or parent) reducer in order to complete the missing case statement.

**i'd like the sub reducer to be self sufficient**